Comparing current quarter with the same quarter from last year
I have a common task that I have to do which involves comparing the current quarter's results with those of the same quarter from last year. I have written this query, but am only getting half the results that I want.
WITH orders_cy AS (
    SELECT 
        prod.ProductID,
        prodc.[ProductCategoryID],
        sod.[Year],
        sod.[Quarter],
        sod.OrderQty as qty_cy
    FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail sod
    LEFT JOIN SalesLT.Product prod ON sod.ProductID = prod.ProductID
    LEFT JOIN SalesLT.ProductCategory prodc ON prod.ProductCategoryID = prodc.ProductCategoryID
    WHERE prodc.ProductCategoryID = 5 AND DATEPART(YY,sod.Saledate) = DATEPART(YY,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
), 
orders_ly as (
    SELECT 
        prod.ProductID,
        prodc.[ProductCategoryID],
        sod.[Year],
        sod.[Quarter],
        sod.OrderQty as qty_ly
    FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail sod
    LEFT JOIN SalesLT.Product prod ON sod.ProductID = prod.ProductID
    LEFT JOIN SalesLT.ProductCategory prodc ON prod.ProductCategoryID = prodc.ProductCategoryID
    WHERE prodc.ProductCategoryID = 5 AND DATEPART(YY,sod.Saledate) = DATEPART(YY,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-1
)

SELECT 
orders_cy.year,
orders_cy.quarter,
sum(orders_cy.qty_cy) as FQSales,
sum(orders_ly.qty_ly) as FQSalesLY,                                                                                             
sum(orders_cy.qty_cy) - sum(orders_ly.qty_ly) as qoq_Diff_Value,
CAST(sum(orders_cy.qty_cy) * 1.0 / sum(orders_ly.qty_ly) -1 AS NUMERIC(18,2)) * 100 AS qoq_DIFF_PERC     
FROM orders_cy
FULL JOIN orders_ly ON 
orders_cy.ProductID = orders_ly.ProductID
AND orders_cy.Quarter = orders_ly.Quarter
GROUP BY orders_cy.ProductCategoryID, orders_cy.[Year], orders_cy.quarter 

The first CTE (orders_cy) returns this data:



ProductID
ProductCategoryID
Year
Quarter
Sales




779
5
2024
3
3


780
5
2024
1
1


785
5
2024
3
2


780
5
2024
4
3


781
5
2024
4
4


782
5
2024
4
2


783
5
2024
3
5


783
5
2024
4
15


784
5
2024
1
5


981
5
2024
1
1


981
5
2024
2
2


981
5
2024
4
2


985
5
2024
4
2


985
5
2024
2
5


987
5
2024
3
5


988
5
2024
4
11



The second CTE (orders_ly) returns this data:



ProductID
ProductCategoryID
Year
Quarter
Sales




779
5
2023
1
1


779
5
2023
2
4


779
5
2023
3
3


780
5
2023
2
5


781
5
2023
2
2


782
5
2023
1
3


783
5
2023
3
7


980
5
2023
2
3


981
5
2023
3
2


982
5
2023
1
3


983
5
2023
1
3


984
5
2023
1
1


985
5
2023
3
2


988
5
2023
1
1


988
5
2023
3
2


991
5
2023
3
5


992
5
2023
3
3


993
5
2023
2
1



The final result should be:



Year
Quarter
FQSales
FYSalesLY
QOQ_DiffValue
QOQ_DiffPerc




NULL
NULL
NULL
41
NULL
NULL


2024
1
7
NULL
NULL
NULL


2024
2
7
NULL
NULL
NULL


2024
3
15
10
5
50.00


2024
4
39
NULL
NULL
NULL



I am supposed to see 12, 15, 25, and NULL in FYSalesLY and the first row above with the 41 should be gone. I think the issue that I have is with the joins. The tables that I have are as follows:
SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail (Contains the sale dates with year, quarter, month)
SalesLT.Product (Contains the product IDs. There are multiple product IDs per broader category ID)
SalesLT.ProductCategory (Lists the product categories corresponding to each product ID)
The CTEs that I use return the correct results for the respective years. The problem emerges when I try to select from both CTEs. Since the sales of some product IDs may not be the same in both years, I figured a FULL OUTER JOIN would be appropriate since I simply want to compare sales for products with the same product category between years. Using a LEFT or RIGHT outer join would lead to the exclusion of some sales records.
PS. If someone could point me to how I can format tables more quickly rather than entering the delimiters in between data points manually that would be great.

Which dbms are you using? (The above SQL is product specific.)

I am using Azure DBMS.

Table and other elements formating see (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

To achieve desired result were need to follow below steps

After getting orders_cy and orders_ly tables, we need to calculate total sales for each quarter for both the current year (2024) and last year (2023).
For each quarter in 2024, compute the total sales from the corresponding quarters in 2023 to get the Yearly Sales Last Year (FYSalesLY).
Further you can calculate the difference and percentage.

For this approach you can try below query:
--calculate total sales for each quarter
WITH current_sales AS (
    SELECT 
        Year,
        Quarter,
        SUM(qty_cy) AS FQSales
    FROM 
        orders_cy -- Replace with your actual table name
    WHERE 
        Year = 2024
    GROUP BY 
        Year, Quarter
),

last_year_sales AS (
    SELECT 
        Year,
        Quarter,
        SUM(qty_ly) AS FYSalesLY
    FROM 
        orders_ly -- Replace with your actual table name
    WHERE 
        Year = 2023
    GROUP BY 
        Year, Quarter
),

-- total sales from the corresponding quarters in 2023, difference and difference in percentage.
Final_output AS (
    SELECT 
        cs.Year,
        cs.Quarter,
        cs.FQSales,
        ly.FYSalesLY,
        cs.FQSales - ly.FYSalesLY AS QOQ_DiffValue,
        CAST((cs.FQSales * 1.0 / ly.FYSalesLY - 1) AS NUMERIC(18,2)) * 100 AS qoq_DIFF_PERC 
    FROM 
        current_sales cs
    LEFT JOIN 
        last_year_sales ly ON cs.Quarter = ly.Quarter
)

SELECT * FROM Final_output;

Output:


It is preferable to make a preliminary grouping, while immediately selecting the amounts for the current and previous year.
This will allow you to use a single table scan.
At the same time, it is possible not to JOIN some tables at all, if columns from these tables are not needed in the resulting output.
In the first example, also used a separate table (subquery) to get a list of quarters. Otherwise, if the source data does not contain sales for any quarter in both years, then this row will not be included in the report.
Perhaps this is not necessary and another example does not use such a subquery.
You should check possible divide to zero when calculate qoq_DIFF_PERC. There used nullif(qty_ly,0) for this check. You can use a different type of verification if your DBMS does not provide such a feature.
See example
select DATEPART(YY,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) yy
  ,t.*
  ,qty_cy - qty_ly as qoq_Diff_Value
  ,CAST((qty_cy*1.0/nullif(qty_ly,0)) -1 AS NUMERIC(18,2)) * 100 AS qoq_DIFF_PERC     
from (select 1 quarter union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4)q
left join (
  select quarter
    ,sum(case when sod.year=DATEPART(YY,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) then orderqty
     else 0 end) qty_cy
    ,sum(case when sod.year=(DATEPART(YY,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-1) then orderqty
     else 0 end) qty_ly
  from SalesOrderDetail sod
  LEFT JOIN Product prod ON sod.ProductID = prod.ProductID
  LEFT JOIN ProductCategory prodc ON prod.ProductCategoryId = prodc.ProductCategoryId
  WHERE prodc.ProductCategoryID = 5 
  group by sod.quarter
)t on q.quarter=t.quarter





yy
quarter
qty_cy
qty_ly
qoq_Diff_Value
qoq_DIFF_PERC




2024
1
7
12
-5
-42.00


2024
2
7
15
-8
-53.00


2024
3
15
24
-9
-38.00


2024
4
39
0
39
null



Simpler example without quarter list:
select DATEPART(YY,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) yy
  ,t.*
  ,qty_cy - qty_ly as qoq_Diff_Value
  ,CAST((qty_cy*1.0/nullif(qty_ly,0)) -1 AS NUMERIC(18,2)) * 100 AS qoq_DIFF_PERC     
from (
  select quarter
    ,sum(case when sod.year=DATEPART(YY,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) then orderqty
     else 0 end) qty_cy
    ,sum(case when sod.year=(DATEPART(YY,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-1) then orderqty
     else 0 end) qty_ly
  from SalesOrderDetail sod
  LEFT JOIN Product prod ON sod.ProductID = prod.ProductID
  LEFT JOIN ProductCategory prodc ON prod.ProductCategoryId = prodc.ProductCategoryId
  WHERE prodc.ProductCategoryID = 5 
  group by sod.quarter
)t 





yy
quarter
qty_cy
qty_ly
qoq_Diff_Value
qoq_DIFF_PERC




2024
1
7
12
-5
-42.00


2024
2
7
15
-8
-53.00


2024
3
15
24
-9
-38.00


2024
4
39
0
39
null



fiddle
If real table SalesOrderDetails don't have columns year and quarter
select DATEPART(YY,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) yy
  ,t.*
  ,qty_cy - qty_ly as qoq_Diff_Value
  ,CAST((qty_cy*1.0/nullif(qty_ly,0)) -1 AS NUMERIC(18,2)) * 100 AS qoq_DIFF_PERC     
from (select 1 quarter union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4)q
left join (
  select datepart(q,SaleDate) quarter
    ,sum(case when datepart(yy,SaleDate)=DATEPART(YY,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) then orderqty
     else 0 end) qty_cy
    ,sum(case when datepart(yy,SaleDate)=(DATEPART(YY,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-1) then orderqty
     else 0 end) qty_ly
  from SalesOrderDetail sod
  LEFT JOIN Product prod ON sod.ProductID = prod.ProductID
  LEFT JOIN ProductCategory prodc ON prod.ProductCategoryId = prodc.ProductCategoryId
  WHERE prodc.ProductCategoryID = 5 
    and SaleDate between dateadd(yy,-1,datetrunc(yy,current_timestamp)) 
              and dateadd(d,-1,dateadd(yy,1,datetrunc(yy,current_timestamp)))
  group by datepart(q,SaleDate)
)t on q.quarter=t.quarter


thanks for the comprehensive answer. I went back to this example and was wondering why not simplify the matter. I have had success with querying without using any CTEs or subqueries whatsoever.
select
sod.[QUARTER],
sum(case when sod.year = 2023 then sod.OrderQty end) as qtrly_sales_2023,
sum(case when sod.year = 2024 then sod.OrderQty end) as qtrly_sales_2024,
sum(case when sod.year = 2024 then sod.OrderQty end) - sum(case when sod.year = 2023 then sod.OrderQty end) as salesdiff,
